# Can not get file class find a file that already exists

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to make a program that prompts the user for input and then creates a file object from the input and handles if the file doesn't exist by re prompting the user. Ive tried the absolute path and the relative path but it always evalutes to false. any help appreciated

```
package Module6B;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Module6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Boolean exceptionThrown = false;
        String origin = "default";
        String destination = "destination";
        String contents = "";

        do {
                exceptionThrown = false;
            try{

                    System.out.println("enter the name of the existing file you want to copy");
                    origin = scan.next();
                java.io.File original = new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Samme\\git\\1322-LAB\\src\\Module6B\\"+origin + ".txt");

                    if(original.exists()) {
                        contents = readFile(origin);
                    }else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }


            }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("the file with the name you entered was not found enter a "
                            + "1 if you would like to try again and enter a valid file name or a 0 if you "
                            + "would like to exit the program");
                    int response = scan.nextInt();
                    if(response == 1) {
                    exceptionThrown = true;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for your time");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Samme\git\1322-LAB\src\Module6B\default.txt` exist ?

Comment: the value of origin is reassigned using the scanner and then used to make the file

Comment: If `original` exists you want to read "`origin`", are you sure about that?

Comment: *"`System.out.println("enter the name of the existing file you want to copy"); origin = scan.next();`"* What''s this from? 'Programming in the 1980s 101'? Offer the poor suffering users a `JFileChooser` to specify a file.

Comment: readFile is a custom method that takes a string for the name and returns a string with the contents of the file. I didn't include it because stack overflow said there was too much code so i kept the part with the problem in it

Comment: why don't you use File parameter for `readFile` method? If you use string parameter, you also have to create a File object again.

Comment: This program uses console to take its input, and doesn't have a gui. Thats the specifications of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.badri.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void read(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        String fileName = scanner.next();
        String filePath = "D://" + fileName + ".txt";
        if (null != filePath) {
            Test.read(filePath);
        }
    }

}
```